where does laravel view that contains 503, 404 and 419 error message located
Where does Laravel view that contains 503, 404 and 419 error messages located?
I have searched the entire vendor fold but can't find it.
I want to get access to it and change a few messages.
Some assistance will be helpful.
Thank you.

do you want to change view or just change error message?

You can publish them using php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-errors. But I'll suggest you to use your custom view instead of modifying default views. Please refer to the official docs.
To create your custom error view create a new file with the error code like resources/views/errors/419.blade.php
